# How to detect that a connection was disabled on c# when transitioning from wifi to cable?

Tags: c#, .net, wifi

I was searching the web to have the events on c# when a network connection is disabled and I came across [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64975/Detect-Internet-Network-Availability) article on CodeProject which uses NetworkChange class from .NET subscribing to the events NetworkAvailabilityChanged and NetworkAddressChanged.

While it does a great job in handling the events for connecting network cards, in my tests it does not raise an event when we are transitioning (disconnecting) from a wi-fi connection to a cabled connection. 
Just to understand my context and before a ton of comments of duplicates come my way, this is my set up:

- I have a Microsoft Surface connected on wi-fi, the cable is previously connected
- I disabled the wi-fi connection expecting the events would be called but instead, it goes off and the connection transitions to my Ethernet local card without raising any events.

Would you have an idea on how to approach this problem? Or would you already came across a scenario like this?

Any ideas is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea, I do not know if there are any methods for this.
When changing network connection, the ip address is also changing. You can either set a static ip for both wifi and ethernet, then create a function that always checks the ip. When there is a change, it means that the connection changed.
I don't know if this will work, but maybe this might help you.

Comment: Hello John and thanks for your answer. The problem with this approach is that, in this specific case, these events (NetworkAvailabilityChanged, NetworkAddressChanged) are not called when transitioning from wi-fi to cable. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is Microsoft Surface a laptop? What I know about laptop is that both ethernet and wifi can be turned on at the same time. So, when you turned off the wifi, it might happen that the network change will not raise an event because it also sees that it is also connected to the ethernet. Maybe if you can disable ethernet or create a function that handles both wifi and eth connection when either one of them are turned on, you may switch to another when a connection changes.

Comment: Exactly, this is a laptop from Microsoft, see [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/surface). I'm gonna try it, up to this point I wasn't able to separate those two events for the two adapters present in this case.